STM32 programmers not always see the target
While practicing STM32 I made an adapter from STDC-14 to a regular 2.54 mm connector with a pin-out like on BluePill development boards.
The wiring diagram is as follows (used flat-ribbon cable, there is no actually twisting of wires):

This adapter works like a charm when used with STLink V3 Set programmer with all dev-boards I have (F103, G030, F030, F4x1, etc.), but behaves differently when I use either NUCLEO-G474 or STLInk V3 mini as a programmer. The problem is that the programmer doesn't see the target MCU when it is :

STM32F103C8T6
STM32F030F4P6
STM32G030C8T6

Interestingly enough, all programmers see the STM32F411CEU6 MCU.
Used Software are:

STM32CubeProgrammer 2.16.0 on Windows 11 x64
All programmers are updated to the latest STLink firmware 3.15.6

Please, suggest, what could the reason(s) for such behaviour?

Please describe the problem further. Is this about programming blank MCUs, or reprogramming MCUs that already run firmware? The FW can do anything they want on the SWD pins, such as disable it or use them as GPIO or alternate function like UART, or set fuse bits to lock out the programming interface. And the programming interface you have cannot use the reset pin as you don't include it. Most often a programming interface has SWD and reset.

@Justme: Doesn't seem to be relevant, since the very SAME mcu on the very same devboard is detectable by one programmer, but not seen by another one.

@Araneus0390 1. What is a clock frequency in both cases? 2. Do data wires in cable are "guarded" by gnd wires on them sides ?

@Theoristos Clock of what? SWD interface? 8000, but I also tried lower. In this one - no. I quickly made the second one where GND is taken from pin 5 of STDC-14 and is passed between SDWCLK and SWDIO - no difference.

@Araneus0390 Yes, clock of debug interface. Can you check functionality with VERY LOW SWD clock freq?

Your problem stems from crosstalk between SWDIO and SWCLK.

make the cable short, say 15cm
make sure the wires carrying SWDIO and SWCLK don't run next to each other; place the GND wire in between them.


@Araneus0390 So you did not take into account that some programers may work with your cabling and some may not, so it could be about the cabling?

@wek shortening did the job, no extra GND wire in between
